# In Spring MVC, Controller is singleton,why my code is thread safe?(Autowired HttpServeltRequest)

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, servlets

It's weird for me.
I have below code:

```
@Controller
public class MyTestController {
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @RequestMapping("/print/")
    public String PrintInfo() throws Exception {

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("name:" +request.getParameter("name"));
        System.out.println("hashcode:" +request.hashCode());

        return "testpage";
    }
}
```

I visited below url at the same time:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp/print/?name=tom
http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp/print/?name=mike
```

It printed:

```
 name:tom
 hashcode:2006506443
 name:mike
 hashcode:2006506443
```

MyTestContorller is singleton. The request's hashcode is same, this means different requests have the same instance.

But why does the  `request.getParameter("name")` give me the correct result?
Maybe the getParameter method is only a method which need read data form other object?

I don't know, it confused me. Anybody can explain it?

Comment: Print the class of your request... it will probably be a JDK proxy, which is able to pull out dependency from the correct scope (hold by thread local on `RequestContextHolder`). I think there is a chapter in Spring documentation dedicated to this...

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection

Comment: magic. and I say it's an evil magic:) the clever trick sabotages our common sense of objects.

Answer (score 3):

Excerpt [from the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) should answer your question:

> **Scoped beans as dependencies**
>
> The Spring IoC container manages not only the instantiation of your
>   objects (beans), but also the wiring up of collaborators (or
>   dependencies). If you want to **inject (for example) an HTTP request
>   scoped bean** into another bean of a **longer-lived scope**, you may choose
>   to inject an AOP proxy in place of the scoped bean. That is, you need
>   to inject a proxy object that exposes the same public interface as the
>   scoped object but that can also retrieve the real target object from
>   the relevant scope (such as an HTTP request) and delegate method calls
>   onto the real object.

The **request scope** is based on a thread-local attribute in [RequestContextHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) (initialized for every request by `DispatcherServlet` by default).

So your `HttpServletRequest` is a dynamic JDK proxy, which upon every method call checks the thread-local attribute to get the real request object and calls it.

The resolvable request dependency itself is registered as a bean as part of the `WebApplicationContext` initialization by [`WebApplicationContextUtils`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html#registerWebApplicationScopes-org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory-).

And here is a little bit simplified diagram (everything in the picture is actually a singleton):

[image: request scope flow]

Comment: Thank you. According your answer,it needs some configurations.But I haven't configure any AOP proxy thing. So how does this magic things happen?

Comment: Nope... this is out of the box thing. Spring does a lot of autoconfiguration for default scenarios. I was just being thorough with explaining what is going on "behind the scenes" :). **You can verify this by placing breakpoints + checking the stack trace** (please do that - it is the best way to understand inner workings of any framework).

Answer (score 0):

I say your **MyTestController** is singleton but the class which implements **HttpServletRequest** is not.

Each time when request is received the servlet container in the underlying server will create a new instance for the class which provided the implementation for the **HttpServletRequest** interface and then the reference of that object will be passed to the **MyTestController**.

It will be just like passing different parameter to a method each time when calling.